# update handler function to save timestamp in couchDB

Tags: couchdb

I am looking to update each document inserted in a couchdb database with the current timestamp.I have referred the document_update_handler feature  which can update individual documents.But what i see from the documentation is that an explicit POST/PUT request to the handler function needs to fired along with docid ,something like this:
http://127.0.0.1:5984/my_database/_design/my_designdoc/_update/in-place-query/mydocId.

What i am looking for is a solution that will automatically create new field with the current timestamp just before a new record is inserted.(I am using lightcouch API on the client side to persist a document).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: yes, I have read the available documentation but didn't see anything that would run some kind of script each time a doc is inserted. As mentioned in the question, from what i read see only a explicit request can invoke the 'update' script.

Comment: Ah, that makes a little more sense. No, you can't automatically do that without an update handler. The closest you can get is to monitor the `_changes` feed and update documents as they are changed. The drawback here is that doesn't intercept the change, so you'll have an extra revision for that script's change.